# iOS Animation >> How to animate a single object to move through several positions

Tags: ios, arrays, animation, cgpoint, chain

I wish to have a `UIImageView` that will "float" over the screen, moving through several positions.
It quite clear how to code it to go from point A to point B using `[UIView animateWithDuration:...]`. It even sounds reasonable to add point C in the "completion" block. You know what? I can also add point D to the completion block of point C, but after that, I start getting a spagetti code that I get lost in.

Nowhere could I find a method where you perform some sort of animation-positions-chain, something like an array of `CGPoints` that run and the `UIImageView` goes between them one after the other.

Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [CAKeyFrameAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) object is extremely powerful and useful when it comes to animating an object through multiple values at multiple timing points.

The animations rely on key-paths, which luckily, center is one, and accept only NSValue objects for points and NSNumber objects for timing.  An example may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998615/how-do-you-cakeyframeanimation-scale) which animates the scale property.  It is meant to be a template for the center property.